# What is the difference between NB and WB entries in mixer_gains.xml?

Tags: audio, system, files

LineageOS for my phone has these sections with entries in the `mixer_gains.xml` file:

```
<path name="gain-incall_nb-handset-mic">
<path name="gain-incall_nb-handset-mic">
<path name="gain-incall_nb-speaker-mic">
<path name="gain-incall_nb-speaker-mic">
<path name="gain-incall_nb-dex-speaker-mic">
<path name="gain-incall_nb-dex-speaker-mic">
<path name="gain-incall_wb-handset-mic">
<path name="gain-incall_wb-handset-mic">
<path name="gain-incall_wb-speaker-mic">
<path name="gain-incall_wb-speaker-mic">
<path name="gain-incall_wb-dex-speaker-mic">
<path name="gain-incall_wb-dex-speaker-mic">
```

But I can't find what NB and WB stand for, or their difference, which makes it hard to know which to alter.

(I'm guessing they *could* stand for "no <something>" vs. "with <something>" but that doesn't help much)

Answer (score 1):

The abbreviations here stand for **narrowband** (nb) and **wideband** (wb).

You can see the list of supported media formats, including the supports audio codecs here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats

For example, the quite common [AMR-NB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_Multi-Rate_audio_codec) codec.

Comment: Can the answer be expanded a bit, as right now it unfortunately answers the question asked, but in a way that isn't usable information :) I now understand the abbreviations, but still have no way to know which of these to modify for a given type of audio output which I figured I'd learn, given the abbreviations. For example,.which codecs are WB vs NB isnt stated, nor is is clear which codecs are used in a phone call (always gsm, or others too?)